Why can't i use the password stored in ".env" file to connect with the mongodb database in express
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Product=require('./models/product.model.js');
const app=express();
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());


const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
if(password)
{
    console.log(password);
}
if (!password) {
  console.error('Error: PASSWARD is not defined in the .env file');
  process.exit(1);
}

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin:${password}@backenddb.nb0lnik.mongodb.net/Node-API?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=BackendDB")
.then(()=>{
    console.log("connected to the Database :)");
    app.listen(3000,()=>{
        console.log("server running on port 3000");
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
    
})

this the code code i use to connect with mongoodb
whenever i try to store the password in my .env file
I get the this  error => 
Troubleshooting that i have already done:
1-Verify Network Access: made my database public to every IP address
2- .env file in the root directory
3- made sure my password is stored in the correct foramate in ".env" file =>  'PASSWORD=""'

Use backtick ` instead of quotes

Because you are using template literal syntax in normal string. You have to use backtick instead of quotes.
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://admin:${password}@backenddb.nb0lnik.mongodb.net/Node-API?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=BackendDB`)
.then(()=>{
    console.log("connected to the Database :)");
    app.listen(3000,()=>{
        console.log("server running on port 3000");
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
    
})

